# `BoundedBTreeMap` equivalent for `StorageMap`?

Tags: storage, storagemap

I'd like to set an upper limit on the size of a storage map. Is there a data structure that supports this check within its methods? Or has anyone defined their own wrapper data structure that performs these checks on each insertion?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a hard limit, then you have to create a wrapper.
The `MaxValues` on `StorageMap` and `CountedStorageMap` are only a soft limit for PoV estimations.

I don't know of any implementations of this. Not sure what you are trying to do either.

Answer (score 2):

There is a counted storage map: [doc](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.CountedStorageMap.html) [implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6507a79b2baf7e4cc6f5868aa490dfe275144f9a/frame/support/src/storage/types/counted_map.rs#L38-L50)

```
pub struct CountedStorageMap<
 Prefix,
 Hasher,
 Key, 
 Value, 
 QueryKind = OptionQuery,
 OnEmpty = GetDefault,
 MaxValues = GetDefault
>(/* private fields */);
```

Comment: As discussed in dms, `insert` and `set` don't perform any max count check. Not sure what the purpose of `MaxValues` is.

Comment: The `MaxValues` is to calculate an upper limit for the worst-case Proof size estimation.